# how to fix Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been stuck on this error

```
Failed to save dataSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
```

key constraint fails (`ticketdatabase`.`ticket`, CONSTRAINT `ticket_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`EventId`) REFERENCES `event`
(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)"

my sql code is

```
INSERT INTO ticket (TicketId,EventId,StatusId,Price,UserId,TypeId) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

the ticket table has a relationship with event table. and the value that i insert actually is already exists on event table but still shows this error.
when i manually insert in php myadmin it inserts fine. but trough the code it raise the error. any help please

Comment: As you are using bind values - it is down to the rest of the code which sets these values.  You will need to add more code to help solve the problem.

Comment: what code is needed to be added please?